# Arrow functions bound at definition time

Tags: javascript

I'm learning es6 arrow functions, how I can get this test to pass?

```
describe('arrow functions have lexical `this`, no dynamic `this`', () => {

it('bound at definition time, use `=>` ', function() {
    var bound = new LexicallyBound();
    var fn = () => getFunction();

    assert.strictEqual(fn(), bound);
});
```

Comment: What's `LexicallyBound`? What's `getFunction`?

Comment: `class LexicallyBound {
  
    getFunction() {
        return () => {
           return new LexicallyBound();
        }
    }
  
     getArgumentsFunction() {
            return function() {return arguments}
         }
  
    }`

Comment: Use "edit" to improve the question, not comments. And based on that definition, you should be getting a `ReferenceError` in your code when you try to call `getFunction` without `bound.` in front of it.

Comment: Thanks i tried edit - it wouldnt let me - too much code

Comment: That doesn't mean you should post it as a comment. It means you should provide more context and explanation.

Comment: Im not sure of the context or explanation, thats why i posted my question in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the function returned by `getFunction` doesn't do anything to demonstrate that it closes over `this`, I don't think it's of any use to use you here.

If the goal is to prove that arrow functions are lexically bound (that is, that they close over `this`), then:

```
it('is lexically bound', function() {
    const obj = {
        arrow: () => {
            return this;
        }
    };
    assert.strictEqual(obj.arrow(), this);
});
```

If `arrow` didn't close over `this`, it would return `obj`, not the current value of `this` in that callback.

Example:

```js
function it(label, test) {
  try {
    test();
    console.log(label, "OK");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(label, "FAILED", e.message);
  }
}
const assert = {
  strictEqual(a, b) {
    if (a !== b) {
      throw new Error("a == b was false");
    }
  }
};

it('Arrow function is lexically bound', function() {
  const obj = {
    arrow: () => {
      return this;
    }
  };
  assert.strictEqual(obj.arrow(), this);
});


it('Non-arrow function is not lexically bound', function() {
  const obj = {
    nonarrow: function() {
      return this;
    }
  };
  assert.strictEqual(obj.nonarrow(), obj);
});
```